# Arrangement of points in a circle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, contest-math

From the 2015 Moscow Mathematical Olympiad:

> The numbers $1$ to $1000$ are arranged on a circle such that each number divides the sum of its two neighbors. Suppose that the number $k$ has two odd neighbors. What's the parity of $k$ ?

I haven't been able to answer the question just yet.

Here are a few things I noticed. The constraint "$x$ divides its two neighbors $a$ and $b$" gets tighter when $x$ grows. For example, if $x=1000$, we must have $1000=a+b$. If $x=999$, we have either $999=a+b$ or $1998=a+b$ (in that case $(a,b)\in \{(1000,998),(998,1000)\}$).

Nevertheless, I can't derive anything useful from $k| a+b$ with $a,b$ being odd numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VqZl.png)

***the numbers from 1 to 1000 have equal number of even(E) and odd(O) numbers.
Let us assume an arrangement where there is at least one group of an odd number with two odd neighbors.This is arrangement A.***
So we have 3 odds one after another. Let all evens in A have two odd neighbors. But then if we group two numbers in the anticlockwise direction we end up with an odd number for every even number, along with some odds extra.Thus it is not possible. 
***Again let in A, we have some evens with one odd & one even neighbor instead of all evens with odd neighbors. But since even doesn't divide even+odd, so this arrangement too is futile.***
Thus, for our given arrangement A, we should have an even number with 2 even neighbors, like: ......,E1,E2,E3,..... In such case,E3 must be followed by E4,
for otherwise we have ...,E1,E2,E3,O,.... but E3 can't divide E2+O. Again, for E4 we must have a consequent E5, and for E5 we must have E6 ;thus this makes all numbers on the circle even,which is impossible.
*Note that we have exhausted all variations of arrangement for A, each time getting a contradiction. Thus arrangement A is impossible.
Therefore, a number with two odd neighbors must be ***even***.*

Answer (score -2):

Just write out the numbers is their order from $1$ to $1000$ on the circle and the condition is satisfied. The answer to the question is now *even*. 
You will have $1000$ between $1$ and $999$ and every other number $n$ will have $n+1$ and $n-1$ whose sum is $2n$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Come up with an arrangement that exists other than the one mentioned.

Comment: You're assuming (without a proof and just because the question ("what's the parity of $k$?") seems to tell you so) that $k$ must always have the same parity under all arrangements. Now you're looking at a special case (when $1,2,3,\ldots,1000$ are in this order) to find the parity. Just because $k$ is even under this arrangement of $1,2,3,\ldots,1000$ doesn't mean $k$ will always be even under other arrangements.

Comment: Without a proof that $k$ is even when no assumption is made on the arrangement, your "answer" should be a comment, at best. And thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @user236182 Well, an olympiad question cannot have two answers. That's for sure. When you are asked 'what is the parity of k?' You can't reply 'Sometimes even, sometimes odd..' can you?